# hover-effect for an adjacent-sibling doesn't work

Tags: css, animation, transition

i have a strange behavior in chrome...

if i have an element[A] with an hover-effect for an element[B] and i put an animation on [A] the transition for element[B] breaks

a short [codepen](http://codepen.io/destroy90210/pen/JYGqQJ?editors=110)

```
.B{
    opacity: 0;
    transtion: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.A{   
    animation: spin 4s linear infinite; // <-- comment this out and the transition works
    &:hover + .B{
        opacity: 1;
   }
}

@keyframes spin { 
    100% {transform: rotate(360deg) }
}
```

Comment: I am using Chrome and the transition works even when the animation is on.

Comment: with 1second?? because it jumps directly from opacity 0 to 1 without 1secon transition

Comment: Yes, with transition.

Comment: hmm strange... with the latest version? and do you have a pc oder mac?

Comment: Latest version of Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: Have you noticed that there is a syntax error ?  ->  transtion

Comment: @harry hmm sam setting like me.

Comment: @vals thank you. at codepen everything is correct written. so that was not the problem.